# Is there a word "qualifiablity", meaning measure of being qualified?

Tags: single-word-requests

Usage: There must have been other factors beside qualifiablity that they considered?

Comment: Yes, but it's spelled "qualifiability", with an i between b and l, to represent the stressed vowel /ɪ/ in /ˌkwanəˌfayə'bɪləti/.

Comment: This isn't a SWR, and it's off-topic as the answer can easily be found using standard resources.

Comment: In your example sentence, I might’ve said “qualifications”